# Querying Solr from remote website

Tags: java, apache, solr

I'm trying to build a website has a search function using Solr running on Jetty.

It works great if I am running the site on the server that Solr is running on, but when i try to access it from any other PC it fails because it is querying the url :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection
```

How can I set it up so queries can run from a url such as

```
http://MyServerName.com/solr/collection
```

or something similar

Comment: How does the snippet for your search-form looks like (from the HTML page)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what you've written so far it looks like you're using solr running in jetty?  So you would need to bind jetty to something other than localhost or just to listen on all interfaces.  You can do this by adding this entry to SelectChannelConnector in the jetty configs:

```
<Set name="Host">your public IP</Set>
```

And then configure your application to query solr through the public IP or hostname.  You'd also need to configure your firewall to allow connections from other hosts on port 8983/TCP.

Comment: Thank you! I'd been beating myself against the documentation brick wall trying to figure out where to make this change.

Comment: Still relevant today +1